# Counting weighted average doesn't work properly sometimes

Tags: python-3.x

I've made a program that counts weighted average and required weighted value to average being equal to our preference. If I want the average be equal to 85 from (the first value in the list is the weight of next values) [[4,72,78],[3,56],[6,93]] and x value of 6 weight it does not output the right value.

```py
def choice(x):
    c = 0
    Choice = True
    choices = []
    while Choice:
        if choices == []:
            if x != 0:
                fill = "weight of required value"
            else:
                fill = "weight of next values"
        else:
            if x != 0:
                fill = "value of wanted weighted average"
            else:
                fill = "value"
        try:
            c = input("Give {}\n" .format(fill))
        except:
            continue
        if isinstance(c, str):
            if c == "":
                Choice = False
                if choices == []:
                    choices = False
                break
            else:
                try: 
                    choices.append(float(c))
                except:
                    continue
        if x != 0 and len(choices) == x:
            break
        c = 0
    return choices
def av(x):
    c = 0
    alist = x[:]
    alist.pop(0)
    for a in alist:
        c += a*x[0]
    return c
def average(k,args):
    c = 0
    n = 0
    for y in range(len(args)):
        for a in range(len(args)):
            c += (av(args[a]))/2
        for b in range(len(args)):
            n += (args[b][0]*(len(args[b])-1))/2
    if k == 1:
        return ([float("{0:.2f}".format(c/n)),c,n])
    else:
        j = float("{0:.2f}".format(c/n))
        print("Weighted average {} from {}" .format(j,args))
def rmark(q,args):
    alist = average(1,args)
    a = float("{:.2f}" .format((((q[1]*(alist[2]+q[0]))-alist[1])/q[0])))
    print("To get weighted average {}, u have to add the value equal to {} of weight {}" .format(q[1],a,q[0]))
    # return a
Continue = True
list_choices = []
while Continue:
    x = 0
    x = choice(0)
    if isinstance(x, list):
        list_choices.append(x)
    elif x == False:
        break

print(list_choices)
rmark(choice(2),list_choices)
average(0,list_choices)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me break it down for you.

`av` function is reducing the size of your lists (x1, x2 and x3) to 1 by popping (`alist.pop(0)`) one element.

Hence, value of `len(x1)-1` is 0, which means value of all multipliers in the denominator of `(av(x1) + av(x2) + av(x3))/((x1[0]*(len(x1)-1)) + (x2[0]*(len(x2)-1)) + (x3[0]*(len(x3)-1)))` is 0. Thus, the error divide by zero.

Comment: OP can fix the error by explicitly copying `x` into `alist`. For a simple 1-d list like shown here, they can do `alist = x[:]`.